# How to get lost jwt from already deployed supabase instance on digitalocean

Tags: docker, docker-compose, digital-ocean, supabase, supabase-database

I have a question that I seek help with.

I deployed Supabase on digital ocean droplet and it is working fine, however, I did lose the jwt of it and I need to create anon API key and service key.

I followed this guide for deploying but don't seem to know exactly what I should do if I lost the jwt, and I don't want to re-deploy another instance or lost data from my Supabase instance, is this possible?

I'm at the point where I can open the console UI of the droplet:
[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What jwt did you lose? Do you mean the Anon Key and the Service role key?

Comment: I was talking about the jwt secret key that is used to generate the anon and service key, I did find out where and what I should do and I will add the answer

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help someone else who is under the same issue, the JWT secret, anon, and service keys of a self-hosted instance of Supabase are saved in a `.env` file that you can access from the console UI like the one in the screenshot.

you should access the snapshot of the Supabase instance by:

1. Listing snapshots of the droplet with the `ls` command
2. Then, entering the Supabase snapshot directory with `cd snapshotName`
3. Then, listing all files in that directory with `ls -a` (the issue I was facing is that I ran only `ls` and this hides .env files from showing in the ubuntu system so make sure you set the `-a` flag)
4. You should see all files now, including the `.env` file.
5. Now you will need to check its content or modify it if you want, by running `nano .env`, it will open a text editor.
6. And That is it, you should be able now to see all keys including the JWT key and other environment variables
7. (optional) if you change some variables, you should run `docker-compose up -d` from the snapshot directory to apply changes.